# ウェブアプリでの録音

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

RailsやCakePHPを使ってユーザーのマイク入力の音声をブラウザ経由で保存することはできますか？

FirefoxやChromeでは SpeechRecognition でマイク入力の許可を取れば音声を取得し、自動認識できることはわかりましたが単純に音声データを転送できるかどうかがわかりませんでした。

環境はMac, Windows, そしてスマホでブラウザのマイクの取り扱いがあるならそれも知りたいです。

Comment: HTML5では[メディアキャプチャ](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)でカメラとマイクにアクセスできます。以前ビデオチャットを作った時に実験しました

Comment: [本家の回答](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25101037/record-audio-using-the-users-microphone-with-html5)

Comment: ありがとうございます。実際にサンプルを動かすことはできたのですが、Rails環境に入れようとするとエラーになってしまい色々試しましたが解決できませんでした…。初めの質問外の事になりますのでまた別に質問を立てさせて頂きます。